# Dropdown field value printing cause additional DB queries in craft CMS 3.7

Tags: craft3

I am fetching an entry with drop-down values and When I print the entry the values are in the entry object. When I try to print the value like entry.dropdown.value it causes additional DB queries to display the data.

As I have a menu structure with a lot of links works were displayed based on the drop-down value. It causes the number of queries to double. Please correct me if am wrong. Am I making the call correctly? or this is how Craft CMS will work? or is there any workaround?

Comment: Accessing the field sholdn't cause additional DB queries if the entry was fully loaded and populated. Please post your template so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @MoritzLost Used like the below,
{% set entry = craft.entries().id(xxx).one() %}
{{ entry.menuType }} 


Here menuType is dropdown feild. and tried {{ entry.menuType.value }} also.

Comment: Hm, I don't think this should cause an additional DB query. How are you determining that it does? Maybe it's just an observer effect, or you're looking at the wrong part of the template.

Comment: @MoritzLost I am determining this when I check the DB queries via debug console in the frontend. if I add those print statements I could see the number of quires spikes.